# ShardStorage goes online automatically

Tags: windows, networking, system

On windows 2012, I have a SCSI shared storage (vendor = starwind) that is online and have its own volume (E:/).

When the machine is restarted, I want the shared to set by default to offline.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to make it clear, the shared storage will keep it original state. If before the restart it was online, when the machine start it will be online. I don't want it to be like this. I want it to start offline always

Answer (score 2):

1. Create PowerShell script:

   Set-Disk -Number %***number of StarWind disk***% -IsOffline $True
2. Create a task in Windows Task Sheduler to run above script on event **257** from StarWind Virtual SAN service to execute script on service start.

Please note that this is not a 100% solution as this will put specified LUN offline not only on host restart but each time you restart StarWind service.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to event 257 may be Event ID 6005, this one is "event log service started" which usually happens on reboot. 
BaronSamedi's suggestion with scripting it on StarWind side makes sense too, just make sure the volume letter is persistent.

PS: May I also wonder about the purpose of this tweak?

Comment: The purpose is to create a cluster between two nodes (We've develop the cluster ourselfs because the cluster solution of Microsoft was not good for us.)
Your solution is very interesting but I'm afraid there will be a very short time where the storage is online in both nodes.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK StarWind is PowerShell scriptable. So you don't create persistent target but rather run your PoSh cmdlet in AutoStart to export LUN.

https://forums.starwindsoftware.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3757